# how to run flutter application without internet access

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am not able to run the  flutter application without  an internet   connection, and
also not able to get packages even if I downloaded  Dart Packages locally that's why  because some packages
are dependent on other dependencies ???

Comment: try with `flutter create --offline .` command

Comment: Use this command: 

flutter pub get --offline

Answer (score 0):

You need an internet connection to download Gradle dependencies, errors points to no network when trying to download these dependencies.

Facing the same problem, every time run project.